# How probable are the numerology outcomes 11,22,33?

Tags: probability, statistics

I found one Stack answer that might be relevant: [numerology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271827/numerology-and-the-possible-combinations) However my question is a bit different. Numerologists like to add up the digits in people's birthdates. The method is to add every number and reduce. For instance a birthdate of January 5, 1980 would be 1 + 5 + 1 + 9 + 8 + 0 = 24. Then further reduce by adding 2 + 4 = 6 which is the final answer.

The possible answers for each birthdate are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and three special outcomes that are not reduced any further: 11,22,33.

So my question is: using birthdates as above are the outcomes 11,22 or 33 rarer than the  outcomes of 1 through to 9?

Comment: why are 11,22,33 not reduced any further?

Comment: Because numerologists class them as special "master numbers". I am not advocating numerology; I am just posing  a number problem using its rules.

Comment: The easiest way to tackle this might be to write a simple program and tabulate the results for all dates in the last 100 years or so.

Comment: The only problem with that is the probabilities would change each century as years change from 1900...to 1800...etc.

Comment: To have a question that can be answered, you need to specify a range of dates that one chooses randomly from.  This century a sum of $33$ is rather improbable because the year does not contribute much.  The $20^{th}$ century is more favorable.  Depending on the range there may not be anything better than a program to count them.